# this is my code in this i want to add date-picker event which gives particular record according to date

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

i don't know how to add question here? please also help me in this..

```
$sql = ("SELECT final_report.customer_id,customer.Customer_name,customer.Customer_email,customer.Customer_address,customer.Customer_phone_num,final_report.Product_id,final_report.total_units,final_report.total_price,final_report.Date
FROM final_report 
INNER JOIN customer
ON customer.Customer_id = final_report.customer_id LIMIT $start_from, $per_page")or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 1):

use `BETWEEN` like that :-

```
where final_report.Date BETWEEN 'date1' and 'date2'
```

or try this :-

```
where final_report.Date='date'
```

Comment: how to define date1 and date2?

Comment: example : from 23/10/2015 to 25/10/2015

Comment: where final_report.Date BETWEEN str_to_date('23/10/2015','%d/%m/%Y') and str_to_date('25/10/2015','%d/%m/%Y')

Comment: try this query like that @DineshGawande

Comment: that was just an example.actually  i am choosing date from datepicker. m not giving it manually each time in query..

Comment: <p>From: </label> <input type="text" id="from" /> To: <input type="text" id="to" /></p> 
<input type="button" id="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form> .. on submit button it call ajax/jquery code..

Comment: hey @rahautos watch my second question which i just ask..(how to add date picker code with join operation query?) it will give u a whole idea...

Comment: $from=$_REQUEST['from'];
$to=$_REQUEST['to'];
where final_report.Date BETWEEN str_to_date('$from','%m/%d/%Y') 
and str_to_date('$to','%m/%d/%Y')